# Autodiscover cannot process the given e-mail address. Only mailboxes and contacts are allowed

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

While sending email using ExchangeService is throwing Exception as Message is: "The Autodiscover service returned an error." and  "Autodiscover cannot process the given e-mail address. 
Only mailboxes and contacts are allowed".

```
public void SendEmail(string to, string cc, string subject, string body,  string emailType)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("test@outlook.com", "test");        
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;            
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("test@outlook.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
            email.ToRecipients.Add(to);
            email.CcRecipients.Add(cc);
            email.Subject = subject;
            email.Body = new MessageBody(body);
            email.Send();
        }
        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;
            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

the above code is working fine with "...@microsoft.com" but not working with "...outlook.com"

can anyone help to resolve issue.[image]

Comment: Are you sure test@outlook.com is hosted by an Exchange Server?

Comment: it is Exchange ActiveSync.

Comment: Which is different from an Exchange account.

Comment: Are you telling it is not hosted in Exchange Server?

Comment: The above code will not work for Exchange ActiveSync?

Comment: It might be an Exchange server under the hood, but you are limited to the EAS API to access it. You need an Office 365 mailbox or an on-prem Exchange mailbox.

Comment: You should be able to send emails from outlook.com using the Office REST API instead of EWS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages

Comment: where can i give my outlook credentials in this api, doesn't accepting sender's password!, can you provide any sample code.